# How to Compare two jbyteArray in JNI?

Tags: android, java-native-interface

i want to compare two jbyteArray if equal in JNI.is there any method like "strcmp"?

Comment: see `GetByteArrayElements`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check that two **jbyteArray**s are actually the same objects, you can test that with `env->IsSameObject(array1, array2)`.

If they are actually distinct objects, you may compare the contents of the arrays with JNI, by matching them element by element. Naturally, it would be wise to first compare the lengths of the two objects, and proceed to pin their elements only if the lengths are equal.

`GetByteArrayElements(array)` returns a C byte array, so the results for two **jbyteArray**s can be compared with `memcmp()`.

Don't forget to release the arrays after usage even if you don't need the Java objects again. Don't forget to check that both **jbyteArray**s are not null before you ever start comparing them.

Comment: thx,it seems that the best way is compare element by element use memcmp().

Comment: If there is any chance that the two objects are actually the same, going straight for byte-by-byte comparison of contents is not only waste of time; in such case, GetByteArrayElements() will inevitably result in unnecessary copy operation.